# Issue while exporting output to CSV in PowerShell Parallel Workflow

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

I am using below script to get the details about port status of multiple remote servers.

```
Workflow Test-OpenPortWF
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [String[]]$Target,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [int]$Port
    )

    If(Test-Path -Path C:\Temp\Results.csv -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ Remove-Item -Path C:\Temp\Results.csv -Force }
    If(Test-Path -Path C:\Temp\Report.csv -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ Remove-Item -Path C:\Temp\Report.csv -Force }

    foreach -parallel -throttle 50 ($t in $Target)
    {
        Sequence
        {
            $Out = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $t -Port $Port -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Select ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,@{N="PortTestSucceeded"; E={$_.tcpTestSucceeded}}
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
            $Out | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append 
        }
    }

    InlineScript
    {
        Import-Csv c:\Temp\Results.csv | Select ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,PortTestSucceeded  | Export-Csv c:\Temp\Report.csv -NoTypeInformation
        Remove-Item c:\Temp\Results.csv -Force
        Write-Host "Execution completed! Check Report.csv for output."
    }
}


# Example use for multiple servers for one port 5985 and export results to CSV file.
# Assuming all target servers are found in c:\temp\Servers.txt (new line separated)
#
# PS C:\Temp> Test-OpenPortWF -Target (Get-Content .\Servers.txt) -Port 5985
```

Mostly it is working but it is not able to give complete results because since we are running this as a parallel workflow, if two servers complete the processing at the same time it will try to write the results to the CSV file at once for both the servers which is resulting in below error. And around 6% results are missing in the CSV file:

> Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : The process cannot access
>   the file 'C:\Temp\Results.csv' because it is being used by another
>   process. At Test-OpenPortWF:54 char:54
>   + 
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], CmdletInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : [localhost]

How can we get around this problem?

Comment: you can get around the problem by not doing anything that requires writing to the same file from multiple sources. [*grin*] ///// i would drop the `workflow` method and use `Invoke-Command` with a list of target systems and a scriptblock. that would send the results back to the calling system, gather them into a $Var, and then write that out to the CSV. some of the benefits are [1] parallel operation [as with a workflow], [2] doing the work on each target instead of on the calling system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use parallel processing, there may be conflicts when multiple threads try to output to your csv file (you run into file locks judging by the error)

Instead, try to output to single temporary files (with unique names) and at the end merge those files into one single report (and delete the temp files)

For example add a counter ($x) in the foreach loop that increments with every iteration ( $x++ ) , then output the results to -Path "C:\Temp\Results_$x.csv"

Comment: That will make it difficult to handle, since we have approx 18000 servers. Even if I throttle for 500  (which is too high limit) it will create 36 files. Any better solution ?

Comment: @SavindraSingh Concurrent access is concurrent. You need to either handle the concurrency yourself or use something that will handle the concurrency for you (e.g. a database).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I agree what you say. It seems there no other solution to this. I have to accept the fact :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a mutex to lock the file I/O operation. Modify your Sequence as such:

```
    Sequence
    {
        $Out = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $t -Port $Port -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Select ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,@{N="PortTestSucceeded"; E={$_.tcpTestSucceeded}}
        $mutex = New-Object System.Threading.Mutex $false, 'NetConnectionTest'
        $mutex.WaitOne() > $null;
        $Out | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append 
        $mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```